# Count markdown links in each file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to figure out how to count and display the number of markdown links in each file in a directory.

For an individual file, I can use `grep` and `wc`:

```
grep -o -P "\[.*?\]\(.*?\)" file1.md | wc -l
```

But how can I do this individually for every file in a directory? The following (and variations using `ls` and other commands) gives me a total for all files:

```
find . -name "*.md" | xargs grep -o -P "\[.*?\]\(.*?\)" | wc -l
```

Ultimately I would like something that resulted in a list showing the filename and the number of matches returned by grep, something like:

```
file1: 7
file2: 11
```

Though the exact formatting of the result isn't important

Comment: Other tools acceptable? Perl or Python this is trivial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one:

```
grep -o -P "\[.*?\]\(.*?\)" *md | cut -d ":" -f 1 | sort | uniq -c
```

it will give output like this:

```
     7 file1
    11 file2
```

If you want, you can transform output using `sed`

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple `for` loop?

```
for file in *.md
do
    echo -n ${file};grep -o -P "\[.*?\]\(.*?\)" ${file} | wc -l
done
```

Comment: This looks close...how can I get it to show the filename for each count?

Answer (score 1):

Would the -c option, which produces a count of matches, be of help? as in

```
find . -name "*.md" | xargs grep -oc -P "\[.*?\]\(.*?\)"
```

Comment: The problem here is that there can be more than one match per line and the -c returns `a count of matching lines`